# How do I delete an event?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working with the external-dragging sample.  I can easily add events to the calendar.  But, I see no method to delete an event, either by clicking a delete button or by dragging the event off the calendar.

How have others solved this issue?

Comment: I did, it does not address this issue, hence the reason for my post.

Comment: Oh, so then you know that there's a `removeEvents` method, which you can build on to delete the events from your calendar as you wish?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with, it's not perfect as the fullcalendar control renders it moving back to it's original location before it's removed, but it does work.

```
$('#calendarTrash').remove();
$('#calendar').children('.fc-content').children().append('<div id="calendarTrash" style="float: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;"><img src="/Content/bin-red-icon.png" /></span></div>');
// Attaches drop event to Calendartrash
$("#calendarTrash").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    var item = ui.helper.context.innerText;
    var answer = confirm("Remove '" + item.trim() + "' from the calendar");
    if (answer) {
        remove = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Then in eventDragStop I have the following

```
if (remove) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id));
    remove = false
}
```

I'm guessing there's a better way, but I have yet to find it.